# Creating Parallax effect using setState

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Currently what I'm trying to achieve is this, where 1 image moves from left to right as the user scrolls down creating a parallax effect:

[image]

Normally with DOM I would use:

```
let image = document.getElementById("image");

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let value = window.scrollY;
  image.style.marginRight = value * 4 + 'px';
  image.style.marginTop = value * 1.5 + 'px';
}
```

But currently I'm trying to replicate this effect in React using setState, but the image doesn't move along with mouse scroll wheel and the layout does not seem right.
So far I've made the effect for when my scroll is between 1 and 300px height where my image moves from center to left side. But I want it so that after 300px till 600px, the image should move from left to right as seen in reference image.

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-hill-2wuko

Current Code:

```
const [leftScroll, setLeftScroll] = useState(false);
  const [topScroll, setTopScroll] = useState(false);
  const [textScroll, setTextScroll] = useState(false);

  useEffect(function onFirstMount() {
    const changeBackground = () => {
      let value = window.scrollY;
      console.log(window.scrollY);

      if (value > 0 && value < 300) {
        setLeftScroll(true);
        setTopScroll(true);
        setTextScroll(true);
      } else {
        setLeftScroll(false);
        setTopScroll(false);
        setTextScroll(false);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);

    return null;
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="background">
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "#0E2043",
          padding: "50px",
          height: "1000px",
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center"
        }}
      >
        <div className="header">Vanuatu</div>
        <img
          className="image"
          style={{
            marginRight: leftScroll ? "300px" : "0px",
            transition: "2s",
            marginTop: topScroll ? "300px" : "0px"
          }}
          alt="random"
          src="https://cdn.britannica.com/87/122087-050-1C269E8D/Cover-passport.jpg"
        />
        <div
          className="text"
          style={{
            marginTop: textScroll ? "300px" : "800px",
            transition: "4s",
            marginLeft: "120px"
          }}
        >
          Minimum Investment
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You dont need to use `state` for this, in fact you shouldn't use state for this.  You do not want to get down the route of rerendering a component on each scroll callback invocation, i.e. every pixel

Comment: @andymccullough so can you recommend me a library or some code that can help me achieve what I want. I basically want my image to be able to move side to side creating a parallax effect along with text moving next to it

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-parallax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Andy mentioned in the comments, you don't want to use `useState` for animations like this. If you already have the code for this feature without React, you can mostly use it in your React code as well. Except that you want to use `useRef` to create a reference to the elements you want to animate.

Also, don't forget to clean up your event listener after the component unmounts.

```
  const imageRef = useRef();
  const textRef = useRef();

  useEffect(function onFirstMount() {
    const changeBackground = () => {
      let value = window.scrollY;

      if (value > 0 && value < 300) {
        textRef.current.style.marginTop = "300px";
        imageRef.current.style.marginRight = "300px";
        imageRef.current.style.marginTop = "300px";
      } else {
        textRef.current.style.marginTop = "800px";
        imageRef.current.style.marginRight = "0px";
        imageRef.current.style.marginTop = "0px";
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="background">
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "#0E2043",
          padding: "50px",
          height: "1000px",
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center"
        }}
      >
        <div className="header">Vanuatu</div>
        <img
          ref={imageRef}
          className="image"
          style={{ transition: "2s" }}
          alt="random"
          src="https://cdn.britannica.com/87/122087-050-1C269E8D/Cover-passport.jpg"
        />
        <div
          ref={textRef}
          className="text"
          style={{
            transition: "4s",
            marginLeft: "120px"
          }}
        >
          Minimum Investment
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```